# Passing an icon component to another component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Lets say I have this CardHeader component and I want to receive a titleIcon props (which is a react component) like this:

```
export default function CardHeader({ title, cardContent, titleIcon }) {
  return (
    <S.MiddleContainer>
      <div className="white-card">
        <div className="campaign-title p-1">
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center pt-1">
            {titleIcon}
            <span id="title">{title}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="pr-2">
            <MdInfo color="#969FAA" size={28} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <p id="border" />
        <div className="campaign-information">
         {cardContent}
        </div>
    </div>
  </S.MiddleContainer>
```

This is where I pass the icon prop

```
import { MdInfo } from 'react-icons/md'

    <Col md={3}>
            <S.ProductContainer>
              <CardHeader 
              title="Sponsors Channel" 
              icon="<MdInfo color="#969FAA" size={28} />"/>

              <Card title="Mobile notification boost" />
            </S.ProductContainer>
          </Col>
```

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

you can pass your icon as a React.Node (not as a string), like so :

```
     <Col md={3}>
        <S.ProductContainer>
          <CardHeader 
          title="Sponsors Channel" 
          icon={<MdInfo color="#969FAA" size={28} />} />

          <Card title="Mobile notification boost" />
        </S.ProductContainer>
      </Col>
```

And you will have access to it via props in **CardHeader** :

```
export default function CardHeader({ title, cardContent, icon }) {
return (
<S.MiddleContainer>
  <div className="white-card">
    <div className="campaign-title p-1">
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center pt-1">
        {icon}
        <span id="title">{title}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="pr-2">
        <MdInfo color="#969FAA" size={28} />
      </div>
    </div>

    <p id="border" />
    <div className="campaign-information">
     {cardContent}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
<CardHeader 
  title="Sponsors Channel" 
  titleIcon={<MdInfo color="#969FAA" size={28} />}
/>
```