# Reactjs Passing a component in other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass a custom component into another component, the parent component should works like a wrapper putting the custom component in a special section at the end, but I'm having this error **Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {...}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.** I read a lot of posts but those solutions doesn't work, here the most similar question but doesn't work for me.

[Passing an icon component to another component in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530822/passing-an-icon-component-to-another-component-in-reactjs)

Wrapper

```
function Wrapper(props: Props) {
    const { title, icon, content } = props
    return (
        <div className={ Styles.wrapperContainer }>
            <h1>{ title }</h1>
            {
                icon &&
                <img src={`/assets/images/${icon || 'notification-bell-icon.svg'}`} alt="" />
            }
            { content }  // <-
        </div>
    )
}
```

calling the Wrapper component

```
<Wrapper
  title="My tittle"
  content={<Button text="press me" type={ButtonTypes.DEFAULT} />}
/>
```

Button Component

```
function Button(props: Props){
    const { type, text, icon } = props
    return (
        <span className={`${Styles.buttonContainer} ${Styles[type]}`}>
            { 
                type === ButtonTypes.ICON_BUTTON ?
                <img src={`/assets/images/${icon}`} alt=""/> :
                (
                    icon ?
                    <><LineIcon icon={icon}/>{ text }</> :
                    { text }
                    )
                }
        </span>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the code you posted, that's how it's done. Where is the error occurring specifically? Is it only when you render `{ content }`? If so, what is that `<Button />` component?

Comment: What type is content in the Wrapper component?

Comment: I think the problem might be the curly braces around the Button component. If you remove those does it work?

Comment: Okay guys, I added Button component in the question n' the `{ content }` was typed as `any`, to avoid type errors.

If I remove the curly braces i get this error:

** Parsing error: '{' expected **

Comment: Why? A component's children are already props.children--this seems like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: I agree with Dave. Why not use props.children?

Comment: @DaveNewton it doesn't matter, the first thing that I tried was with `props.children` but the same happened, I read about that here https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment

Comment: That's not the point--my point was that this seems like a wheel unnecessary to reinvent.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, thanks for your help, I found a problem with the `<Button />` Component, I changed like this n' it works, adding `<></>` tag over the `{ text }` works too.

Thanks

```
function Button(props: Props){
    const { type, text, icon } = props
    return (
        <span className={`${Styles.buttonContainer} ${Styles[type]}`}>
            { 
                type === ButtonTypes.ICON_BUTTON ?
                <img src={`/assets/images/${icon}`} alt=""/> :
                (
                    <>
                        { icon && <LineIcon icon={icon}/> }
                        { text }
                    </>
                )
            }
        </span>
    )
}
```